# Is it reasonable for numerals to behave like verbs?

Tags: conlang-creation, naturalism, syntax, verbs, natural-languages

I am aware that adjectives can pattern like verbs in some natural languages. Is it reasonable for numerals to do the same? Thus

```
Some balls four.
There are four balls.

Fouring the balls were orange.
The four balls were orange.
```

Of course, my conlang has more interesting verbal forms than we have in English. Is something like this attested in a natural language?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One clear-cut example of a language that treats many things like predicates, numerals included, is Khoekhoe.

[Khoekhoe](https://web.stanford.edu/group/cslipublications/cslipublications/HPSG/2014/hahn.pdf) marks many kinds of predicates the same way, including *numerals*. The paper argues that all three of the open word classes (nouns, verbs, and adjectives) in Khoekhoe can be analyzed as primarily predicates and non-predicative usage requires more morphology, specifically person-number-gender (PNG) affixes. Nominalizing stuff with a PNG clitic is extremely productive in Khoekhoe.

Here is an excerpt from page 3 of 21 from *Predication and NP Structure in an
Omnipredicative Language: The Case of
Khoekhoe* by Michael Hahn.

> Khoekhoe is an SOV language. The V slot may be occupied by a word from
>   any of the three open word classes: a verb (1a), an adjective (1b), or
>   a noun (1cd). Both commons nouns (1c) and proper nouns (1d) can be
>   used. Even deictic elements (1e-f), numerals (1g), and possessives
>   (1h) can act as predicates. While the choice of the TAM marker depends
>   on the predicate, the syntactic behaviour of the different predicates
>   is entirely parallel:

Here are some examples from the paper.

```
1a) saa=ts  ge   ra  |khii
    you=2ms DECL TAM come
    You (m) are coming.

1b) om=s      ge    (a)  kai
    house=3fs DECL  TAM  big
    The house is big.

1c) saa=ts    ge    (a)  gao-ao
    you=2ms   DECL  TAM  king
    You are a king.

1d) saa=ts    ge    (a)  Petru
    you=2ms   DECL  TAM  Peter.
    You are Peter.

1e) om=s      ge    (a)  nee.
    house=3fs DECL  TAM  this
    The house is this one.

1f) tii=ta    ge    (a)   saa
    I=1sg     DECL  TAM   you
    I am you.

1g) tara=di   ge    a  !nona
    women=3fp DECL TAM three
    The women are three.

1h) om=s      ge    a   tii
    house=3fs DECL TAM  mine
    The house is mine.
```